# rearrangement of series in $\ell^p$ space

Tags: sequences-and-series, lp-spaces

Let $x \in \ell^p$, where $1 \leq p < \infty$.

Notice that we can write $x= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x_n e_n$, where $e_n=(0, \cdots, 1,0, \cdots )$ i.e. $1$ is at the nth term.

I want to show that that the rearrangement of the series $ \sum_{n\in \mathbb{N}} x_n e_n =\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x_n e_n= x$.

This is what I have so far:

What we want to show is equivalent to showing $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |x_n e_n|=x$.

$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |x_n e_n|= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |x_n e_n|= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |x_n|= \| x\|_1 < \infty $

Let $\epsilon >0$.

Since $x= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x_n e_n$. There exists some $N$ such that for all $k>N$,

$\| x- \sum_{n=1}^{k}x_n e_n\| < \epsilon$.

So $\| x- \sum_{n=1}^{k} | x_n e_n| \|\leq \| x- \sum_{n=1}^{k}x_n e_n\|<\epsilon$.

Thus, $x= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |x_n e_n|$.

So we've shown that $ \sum_{n\in \mathbb{N}} x_n e_n =\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x_n e_n= x$.

Could someone check if my steps are valid?

I'm not so sure about $x= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |x_n e_n|=\sum_{n\in \mathbb{N}} x_n e_n =\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x_n e_n $

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Oh I think I got it... You do something similar to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1444445/series-rearrangement. But please let me know if you see any mistakes.