# If $\{a_n\}$ and $\{b_n\}$ are absolutely summable, why is the arrangement of terms in $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n\cdot\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n$ irrelevant?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

My question below is based on a section from Chapter 23, "Infinite Series", of Spivak's *Calculus*.

Consider the task of multiplying two infinite series. That is, we want to compute

$$\left (\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty a_n \right )\cdot \left ( \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty b_n \right )=(a_1+a_2+a_3+...)\cdot (b_1+b_2+b_3+...)$$

All possible products $a_ib_j$ can be arranged into a two-dimensional array. We can arrange the elements of this array in a sequence in an infinite number of ways. Here is an example
[image]

> Let $\{c_n\}$ be a sequence of this sort, containing each product
> $a_ib_j$ just once.
>
> We might naively expect to have
>
> $$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty c_n=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty
> a_n\cdot\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty b_n$$
>
> but this isn't true, nor is this really surprising since we've said
> nothing about the specific arrangement of the terms. The next theorem
> shows that the result does hold **when the arrangement of terms is
> irrelevant**
>
> **Theorem 9** If $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ and $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty b_n$ converge absolutely, and $\{c_n\}$ is
> any sequence containing the products $a_ib_j$ for each pair $(i,j)$,
> then
>
> $$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty c_n=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty
>  a_n\cdot\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty b_n$$

Why is the arrangement of terms irrelevant in the scenario in Theorem 9?

Comment: Related to rearrangement of absolute convergent series. See this posting for example https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1444445/121671

Comment: See page 112 of https://mtaylor.web.unc.edu/wp-content/uploads/sites/16915/2018/04/anal1v.pdf

Comment: @OliverDíaz I am aware of the linked Theorem. It is the theorem that comes right before the one in the question above.

Comment: @evianpring: since the rearrangement theorem does not depend on the Cauchy product theorem, just understand the former to deal with the later.

Comment: @evianpring: For a thorough and clear presentation of rearrangement, subsidies, double series and and product of series I recommend pages 196-203 Of Tom Apostol's Mathematical Analysis, 2nd edi. book. To properly define the product of two series as a series itself, double series and rearrangement of them are the tools to have a rigorous analysis. Once that is understood, the nicest result is: Suppose $\sum_na_n$  and $\sum_nb_n$ converge absolutely. Then $\sum^\infty_{n=0}(\sum^n_{k=0}a_kb_{n-k})$ converges to $(\sum_na_n)(\sum_nb_n)=\sum_{n,m}a_nb_m$

Answer (score 1):

Let's analyze the proof of Theorem 9 for insights.

Consider the sequence $p_L=\sum\limits_{i=1}^L |a_i| \sum\limits_{j=1}^L |b_j|$. This is a sequence of partial sums.

For example,

$$p_1=|a_1||b_1|$$

$$p_2=|a_1||b_1|+|a_1||b_2|+|a_2||b_1|+|a_2||b_2|$$

This sequence converges because the following limit exists

$$\lim\limits_{L\to\infty} p_L=\lim\limits_{L\to\infty} \sum\limits_{i=1}^L |a_i| \cdot \lim\limits_{L\to\infty}\sum\limits_{j=1}^L |b_j|\tag{1}$$

We can use this formula equation because both right-hand side limits exist.

Notice that any rearrangement of either $\{a_n\}$ or $\{b_n\}$ leads to the same limits for these sequences and also for $p_L$.

This follows from the following theorem

> **Theorem 8** If $\sum\limits_{n=1} a_n$ converges absolutely and $\{b_n\}$ is any rearrangement of $\{a_n\}$ then $\sum\limits_{n=1} b_n$ also converges absolutely and $\sum\limits_{n=1} a_n=\sum\limits_{n=1}b_n$

**I am speculating here, but I think this means that by rearranging the individual sequences we can get different orders of terms in the partial sums and in $\lim\limits_{L\to\infty} p_L$** and in each case $p_L$ converges to the same number. I am not totally sure about this, because as $p_L$ is constructed it doesn't seem that we get all the possible orders of terms $a_ib_j$.

If $\{a_n\}$ and $\{b_n\}$ were summable but not absolutely summable, then we could not just rearrange the sequences and still be sure that we've maintained

$$\lim\limits_{L\to\infty} p_L=\lim\limits_{L\to\infty} \sum\limits_{i=1}^L a_i \cdot \lim\limits_{L\to\infty}\sum\limits_{j=1}^L b_j\tag{2}$$

Thus, we cannot be sure that $p_L$ converges, since it depends on the order of the terms in the product of the sequences.

In the case of absolute convergence of $\{a_n\}$ and $\{b_n\}$ we know that whatever order of terms we choose in $p_L$ it converges.

**Here is the rest of the proof, just for the record. But the main reasoning is above.**

Since $\{p_L\}$ is a Cauchy sequence, then for $L$ and $L'$ large enough with $L'>L$ we have

$$\left | \sum\limits_{i=1}^{L'} |a_i|\sum\limits_{j=1}^{L'} |b_j|- \sum\limits_{i=1}^{L} |a_i|\sum\limits_{j=1}^{L} |b_j|\right |<\frac{\epsilon}{2}<\epsilon$$

The left-hand side means we only keep terms of $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{L'} |a_i|\sum\limits_{j=1}^{L'} |b_j|$ for which $i$ or $j$ is larger than $L$. Thus we have

$$\sum\limits_{i\text{ or } j > L}|a_i||b_j|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}<\epsilon$$

Now, let $\{c_n\}$ be any sequence such that each term is of form $a_ib_j$ for each pair $(i,j)$.

Suppose $N$ is large enough that the terms $c_n$ for $n\leq N$ include every term $a_ib_j$ for $i,j<L$.

Then the difference

$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{N} c_n-\sum\limits_{i=1}^{L} a_i\cdot \sum\limits_{j=1}^{L} b_j$$

consists of terms $a_ib_j$ with $i>L$ or $j>L$, so

$$\left |\sum\limits_{n=1}^{N} c_n-\sum\limits_{i=1}^{L} a_i\cdot \sum\limits_{j=1}^{L} b_j\right |\leq \sum\limits_{i\text{ or } j > L}|a_i||b_j|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}<\epsilon$$

To put it in more words, $\{c_n\}$ is a sequence of terms $a_ib_j$. If the first $N$ terms contain terms $a_ib_j$ for $i,j<L$, then $\sum\limits_{i\text{ or } j > L}a_ib_j$ represents all the (infinite) other terms of this kind, which have $i$ or $j>L$. The rest of the terms in $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{N} c_n$ will be a subset of these infinite other terms.

Then,

$$\left | \sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty a_i \sum\limits_{j=1}^\infty b_j-\sum\limits_{n=1}^{N}c_n\right |$$

$$=\left | \sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty a_i \sum\limits_{j=1}^\infty b_j-\sum\limits_{i=1}^{L} a_i \sum\limits_{j=1}^{L} b_j+\sum\limits_{i=1}^{L} a_i \sum\limits_{j=1}^{L} b_j-\sum\limits_{n=1}^{N}c_n\right |$$

$$=\left | \sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty a_i \sum\limits_{j=1}^\infty b_j-\sum\limits_{i=1}^{L} a_i \sum\limits_{j=1}^{L} b_j\right |+\left |\sum\limits_{i=1}^{L} a_i \sum\limits_{j=1}^{L} b_j-\sum\limits_{n=1}^{N}c_n\right |$$

$$<2\epsilon$$